# Error while saving screenshot with any screenshot software

Tags: permissions, screenshot

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to take a screenshot with the default screenshot utility or Shutter a dialog box appears saying that `/home/user/Pictures` is a read-only file system.

I checked the permission of the folder but it was set to the default value: creating and deleting files. What might have gone wrong here? How can I solve this?

This I didn't have this problem before, not even yesterday. And as far as I remember, I didn't install any software that might have changed the permissions.

Comment: What is your folder's owner and group on the file permissions?

Comment: The owner of that folder is me, that is `minhaz`, the permission is `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: I can take screenshots again :/ No errors or whatsoever! I wonder what was the problem, and how it got solved. I just shut off my PC for a while, and now it's gone!

Answer (score 0):

can you manually make a file in Pictures? One command to do so is this:

```
touch ~/Pictures/test.fyle
```

Comment: Yes, I can do so from terminal. Only the sceenshot applications seem to have the permission problem. I can even save images in that folder with Gimp!

Comment: Thanks for looking in to my problem @psny :) The problem is solved. When you asked if I can manually make files, I tried that with terminal as well as with Gimp. Then Tried out Shutter again, and it worked!

Comment: you're welcome. I'm not sure what happened, though.